# Divide a rectangle into squares

Tags: java, hashmap, grid, coordinates

I have a rectangle with the co-ordinates A,B,C,D which are respectively having the co-ordinates:

```
A->(3,9)
B->(6,9)
C->(6,6)
D->(3,6)
```

where A is the top left co-ordinate and D is the bottom left co-ordinate.

I want to divide the rectangle into 25 grids and assign each grid a number.For example[image: grid]

So I tried like

```
double width =  6-3=3;
double height = 9-6=3;

grid width=3/5=0.6
grid height=3/5=0.6
```

Now I want to assign the grid an id and their co-ordinates like

```
1  ->  (3,9),(3.6,9),(3.6,8.4),(3,8.4)
```

and so on.

So I am implementing a hash map  to store the information.

```
HashMap<Integer, Double[]> hmap = new HashMap<Integer, Double[]>();
```

But I am confused how I can get the grid id's and the

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Why `Double[]`, and not `double[]`? Also, what code have you tried so far?

Comment: Define a `Point` with `x` and `y` coordinates. And then make sure your `Integer`(grid id) is mapped to a `List<Point>` and to test this `assertTrue(list.size() == 4)`, considering the quad grid.

Comment: including the corners (as in your question `(3,9),(3.6,9),(3.6,8.4),(3,8.4)....` ) it is a 6x6 grid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can produce the ids and (36) coordinates by simple double loop:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Map<Integer, double[]> hmap = new HashMap<>();

    int id = 0;
    for (double height = 9.0 ; height >= 6.0; height -=0.6) {

        for (double width = 3.0 ; width <= 6.0; width+=0.6) {

            hmap.put(id++, new double[] {width, height}) ;
        }
    }

    //output 
    for(Integer iD : hmap.keySet()) {

        System.out.printf("%2d  %3.2f %s %3.2f \n",iD,hmap.get(iD)[0],"-",hmap.get(iD)[1]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your above code produce the id's but I am facing some trouble when I wanted to group the coordinates.For example `1  ->  (3,9),(3.6,9),(3.6,8.4),(3,8.4)` likewise i wanted to pair for each grid id.Could you please help me?

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you need. Doesn't `HashMap<Integer, Double[]>` give a pair for each id ?

Comment: HashMap<Integer, Double[]> gives the individual points and co-ordinates but I am now planning to group them in the sense I need `1  ->  (3,9),(3.6,9),(3.6,8.4),(3,8.4)` instead of  `1  ->  (3,9)`.So basically I want to group the individual point which form the grids

Comment: A solution for it can be quiet simple, but I think this is a different question and should be posted separately. Post a message here when you do.

Comment: [link for the new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42943311/how-to-group-points).

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to represent a grid data structure is to use a two dimensional array of the data type that the grid consists of you could declare one like

```
Double[][] grid = new Double[5][5]
```

this is basically an array of arrays 5 arrays of 5 arrays or more simply put 5 rows and 5 columns. When you have data stuctured this way it makes it really easy to find specific squares in that grid and update/view them or iterate over every square in the entire grid, every row, every column etc. The way you can go about iterating through a 2d array is to use two nested loops. The outer reprsenting the number of rows you have and the inner representing the number of records or data for each row so for example for the above grid you could have

```
for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
    for(int j = 0; j < 5; j++){
        System.out.println(grid[i][j].toString());
    }
}
```

the above code hits every square and prints the contents of that square of data in the grid. If you wanted to for example switch from 2d to 3d you would have 3 nested for's one doing a row the other doing a square to get a plane and the other to do the z to get the depth and then you would have a 3 dimensional data structure that is easily accessed and iterated over. I just finished up making a game of chess using a 2d array of JButtons's so let me know if you have any further questions.

Comment: yeah as you said the two dimensional array is easy to maintain and the code is accessing the grids but my question is when I access the grid how to get the co-ordiantes of the grid?

Comment: Use `double[]` instead of `Double[]` and do store doubles (the coordinates) in it, rather than `int`

Comment: @Josh to get the coordinates you could reference i and j directly, for example if you wanted to find the coordinates of all squares that are greater than 100 (arbitrary condition) you would use the above nested loop and record i and j for all that meet the condition, you then can do whatever you want with the i and j's, i recommend making a Coordinate object and having an arraylist of them for your needs