# How to group points

Tags: java

This a program which divides a rectangle into grids and have the individual point's co-ordinates printed.

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {

    Map<Integer, double[]> hmap = new HashMap<>();

    int id = 0;
    for (double height = 9.0 ; height >= 6.0; height -=0.6) {

        for (double width = 3.0 ; width <= 6.0; width+=0.6) {

            hmap.put(id++, new double[] {width, height}) ;
        }
    }

    //output 
    for(Integer iD : hmap.keySet()) {

        System.out.printf("%2d  %3.2f %s %3.2f \n",iD,hmap.get(iD)[0],"-",hmap.get(iD)[1]);
    }
}
```

[image]

I am now planning to group them in the sense I need 1 -> (3,9),(3.6,9),(3.6,8.4),(3,8.4) instead of 1 -> (3,9).So basically I want to group the individual point which form the grids.Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: So you want to group them by their respective rows and columns?  Just one or the other, or both?  Edit: I think I see, you want the points that form the four corners of each cell grouped together, yes?

Comment: Now I have all the individual points and i want to form the points which forms the grid

Comment: This may be irrelevant, but why do you want that?  There will be a lot of duplication since each cell shares as many as all four corners with its neighbors.

Comment: Because I want to know which points form the grid id 1.For example `1 -> (3,9),(2.4,9),(2.4,8.4),(3,8.4)` and `2-> (3.6,9),(4.2,9),(4.2,8.4),(3.6,8.4)`.As you said yeah there will be shared co-ordinates for every grid

Comment: But *why* do you want to know that?  What will it ultimately be used for?  It's not a big deal, but I'm smelling a little XY Problem here, and I just want to actually address any questions that might be related to what you are asking.

Comment: Because I want to give the predefined grid_id and the co-ordinates it form so that I will use my grid_id only afterwards so I do not need to worry about the other things.(like for search in the grid then if I have the coordinates which form the grid then I can say a random coordinate falls on which grid id)

Comment: OK, there are existing UI elements that do that already.  You can make a GridLayout and it will handle all the x and y coordinates for you.  Would that work?

Comment: But here I am not using any UI elements just the logic to do more calculations in the backend.So it would be helpful if you can help me to group these coordinates.

Comment: Sounds like homework.....

Comment: No it is not a home work I am developing a web app and this one is used to implement a search on grid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there's probably several ways to solve this.  The way I did it was to notice that your grid cell numbers form a grid themselves.  Numbers 1 to 5 are the first row, numbers 6 to 10 are the second, etc.  That means I can find the row and column of any cell like this:

```
      int col = (cell-1) % 5;
      int row = (cell-1) / 5;
```

Once I do that, finding the coordinates is pretty easy, just algebra.  Your top row starts at 9 and decreases by 0.6 for each row.  The bottom of that cell is always 0.6 less than the top.  This gives the y coordinates.  A similar calculation can be made for the x coordinates.

To find the coordinates, just call the static method below with its cell number. I had to subtract one from the cell parameter because the modulus counting starts at 0, and your counting starts at 1.

```
public class GridCoord
{
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      for( int i = 1; i <= 25; i++ ) {
         System.out.println( Arrays.toString( gridCoordinates( i ) ) );
      }
   }
   public static double[] gridCoordinates( int cell ) {
      int col = (cell-1) % 5;
      int row = (cell-1) / 5;
      double y1 = 9.0 - row * 0.6;
      double y2 = y1 - 0.6;
      double x1 = 3.0 + col * 0.6;
      double x2 = x1 + 0.6;
      return new double[] {x1, x2, y1, y2};
   }
}
```

Output:

```
run:
[3.0, 3.6, 9.0, 8.4]
[3.6, 4.2, 9.0, 8.4]
[4.2, 4.8, 9.0, 8.4]
[4.8, 5.3999999999999995, 9.0, 8.4]
[5.4, 6.0, 9.0, 8.4]
[3.0, 3.6, 8.4, 7.800000000000001]
[3.6, 4.2, 8.4, 7.800000000000001]
[4.2, 4.8, 8.4, 7.800000000000001]
[4.8, 5.3999999999999995, 8.4, 7.800000000000001]
[5.4, 6.0, 8.4, 7.800000000000001]
[3.0, 3.6, 7.8, 7.2]
[3.6, 4.2, 7.8, 7.2]
[4.2, 4.8, 7.8, 7.2]
[4.8, 5.3999999999999995, 7.8, 7.2]
[5.4, 6.0, 7.8, 7.2]
[3.0, 3.6, 7.2, 6.6000000000000005]
[3.6, 4.2, 7.2, 6.6000000000000005]
[4.2, 4.8, 7.2, 6.6000000000000005]
[4.8, 5.3999999999999995, 7.2, 6.6000000000000005]
[5.4, 6.0, 7.2, 6.6000000000000005]
[3.0, 3.6, 6.6, 6.0]
[3.6, 4.2, 6.6, 6.0]
[4.2, 4.8, 6.6, 6.0]
[4.8, 5.3999999999999995, 6.6, 6.0]
[5.4, 6.0, 6.6, 6.0]
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 1 second)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

/**
 * A solution base on using a custom data structure representing a Cell.
 * Each cell is defined by 4 points, each point represented by a data 
 * structure Point2D holding coordinates (2 double values).
 * You can make use of javafx.geometry.Point2D if you have access to javafx.
 *Alternatively make your own simple Point2D class as in the following code:
 */
class Cells{

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        //map to hold cell number and cell
        Map<Integer, Cell> hmap = new HashMap<>();


        double maxHeight=9.0, minHeight = 6, maxWidth= 6.0, minWidth = 3.0, step =0.6;
        int cellNumber = 1;

        //iterate on height (row by row top to bottom)
        for (double height = maxHeight ; height > (minHeight+step); height -= step) {

            //iterate over columns, left to right
            for (double width = minWidth ; width < (maxWidth -step) ; width+=step) {

                Point2D tl = new Point2D(width, height);
                Point2D tr = new Point2D(width+step, height);
                Point2D br = new Point2D(width+step, height-step);
                Point2D bl = new Point2D(width, height-step);
                Cell cell = new Cell(tl, tr, br, bl);


                //add cell to map
                hmap.put(cellNumber++, cell) ;
            }

        }

        //output
        for(Integer cellNum : hmap.keySet()) {

            System.out.printf("Cell:%2d  %s\n",cellNum, hmap.get(cellNum));
        }
    }
}

//Represents a cell by its four point
class Cell{

    //Top left, top right, bottom right, bottom left points
    private Point2D tl, tr, br,  bl;
    Cell(Point2D tl, Point2D tr, Point2D br, Point2D bl){

        this.tl=tl; this.tr=tr; this.br=br; this.bl=bl;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {

        return (tl+","+tr+","+br+","+ bl);
    }
}

//a container to hold 2 coordinates. Alternatively import
//import javafx.geometry.Point2D
class Point2D {

    private double x,y;

    Point2D(double x, double y){
        this.x = x; this.y = y;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {

        return (String.format("[%3.2f %s %3.2f]", x,"-",y ));
    }
}
```

Output :

> Cell: 1  [3.00 - 9.00],[3.60 - 9.00],[3.60 - 8.40],[3.00 -
>   8.40] 
> Cell: 2  [3.60 - 9.00],[4.20 - 9.00],[4.20 - 8.40],[3.60 - 8.40] 
> Cell: 3  [4.20 - 9.00],[4.80 - 9.00],[4.80 - 8.40],[4.20 - 8.40] 
> Cell: 4  [4.80 - 9.00],[5.40 - 9.00],[5.40 - 8.40],[4.80 - 8.40] 
> Cell: 5  [5.40 - 9.00],[6.00 - 9.00],[6.00 - 8.40],[5.40 - 8.40] 
> Cell: 6  [3.00 - 8.40],[3.60 - 8.40],[3.60 - 7.80],[3.00 - 7.80] 
> Cell: 7  [3.60 - 8.40],[4.20 - 8.40],[4.20 - 7.80],[3.60 - 7.80] 
> Cell: 8  [4.20 - 8.40],[4.80 - 8.40],[4.80 - 7.80],[4.20 - 7.80] 
> Cell: 9  [4.80 - 8.40],[5.40 - 8.40],[5.40 - 7.80],[4.80 - 7.80] 
> Cell:10  [5.40 - 8.40],[6.00 - 8.40],[6.00 - 7.80],[5.40 - 7.80] 
> Cell:11  [3.00 - 7.80],[3.60 - 7.80],[3.60 - 7.20],[3.00 - 7.20] 
> Cell:12  [3.60 - 7.80],[4.20 - 7.80],[4.20 - 7.20],[3.60 - 7.20] 
> Cell:13  [4.20 - 7.80],[4.80 - 7.80],[4.80 - 7.20],[4.20 - 7.20] 
> Cell:14  [4.80 - 7.80],[5.40 - 7.80],[5.40 - 7.20],[4.80 - 7.20] 
> Cell:15  [5.40 - 7.80],[6.00 - 7.80],[6.00 - 7.20],[5.40 - 7.20] 
> Cell:16  [3.00 - 7.20],[3.60 - 7.20],[3.60 - 6.60],[3.00 - 6.60] 
> Cell:17  [3.60 - 7.20],[4.20 - 7.20],[4.20 - 6.60],[3.60 - 6.60] 
> Cell:18  [4.20 - 7.20],[4.80 - 7.20],[4.80 - 6.60],[4.20 - 6.60] 
> Cell:19  [4.80 - 7.20],[5.40 - 7.20],[5.40 - 6.60],[4.80 - 6.60] 
> Cell:20  [5.40 - 7.20],[6.00 - 7.20],[6.00 - 6.60],[5.40 - 6.60] 
> Cell:21  [3.00 - 6.60],[3.60 - 6.60],[3.60 - 6.00],[3.00 - 6.00] 
> Cell:22  [3.60 - 6.60],[4.20 - 6.60],[4.20 - 6.00],[3.60 - 6.00] 
> Cell:23  [4.20 - 6.60],[4.80 - 6.60],[4.80 - 6.00],[4.20 - 6.00] 
> Cell:24  [4.80 - 6.60],[5.40 - 6.60],[5.40 - 6.00],[4.80 - 6.00] 
> Cell:25  [5.40 - 6.60],[6.00 - 6.60],[6.00 - 6.00],[5.40 - 6.00]